# Only the last button's onclick works

Tags: javascript, html

I inserted into `.content` some buttons with `innerHTML`, and I used `addEventListener` to got the onclick event and show a message when each button clicked. The problem is that only the last button's `onclick` works, What is the problem?

```js
var x = document.getElementById("content");

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    x.innerHTML += `
    <button type="button" class="click-btn" id="click-btn-id" value="${i}">
        click me
    </button>
  `;
  
  // get last button that was INNER to .content
  var btn_option = document.getElementsByClassName("click-btn");
  var btn = btn_option[btn_option.length - 1];

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log('clicked!');

  });

}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: You're only adding the event to the last button with this line of code `var btn = btn_option[btn_option.length - 1];`... Seems deliberate

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking. The code you shared, including the comment in it, and your questions seem out of sync?

Comment: Probally copied code and remark is still there.

Comment: @Dominik That is for  finding the last .button that was inner to the .content, because you can see in the code above there are 2 buttons that are inner and must be clickable. I add an eventListener for every button that is inner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you override the content by setting `innerHTML` directly. 
 The working way is to append button html to the DOM using `insertAdjacentHTML`, for example.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("content");

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  buttonHTML = `
    <button type="button" class="click-btn" id="click-btn-id" value="${i}">
        click me
    </button>
  `;
  x.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", buttonHTML);
  // get last button that was INNER to .content
  var btn_option = document.getElementsByClassName("click-btn");
  var btn = btn_option[btn_option.length - 1];

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("clicked!");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `var btn = btn_option[btn_option.length - 1]` makes you select the second button as `btn-option.length - 1` is 1. Thats means you select the button at index 1. and not both 0 & 1.
Try using

```
var x = document.getElementById("content");

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    x.innerHTML += `
    <button type="button" class="click-btn" id="click-btn-id" value="${i}">
        click me
    </button>
  `;
  
  var btn_option = document.getElementsByClassName("click-btn");

btn-option.addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log('clicked!');

            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("content")

wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
  var btn_option = document.getElementsByClassName("click-btn");
  Object.keys(btn_option).forEach(function(key){
    if(ev.target == btn_option[key]){
      console.log("btn "+ btn_option[key].getAttribute("value") +" click")
    }
  })
})

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  wrapper.innerHTML += `
    <button type="button" class="click-btn" value="${i}">
        click me
    </button>
  `;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can loop your code like this.

```
var x = document.getElementById("content");
for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  x.innerHTML += `<button type="button" class="click-btn" id="click-btn-id" value="${i}"> click me</button>`;
// get last button that was INNER to .content
  var btn_option = document.getElementsByClassName("click-btn");
  var len=btn_option.length;
  for (let i=0; i<len; i++){
    var btn = btn_option[i];
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log('clicked!'+i);
  });
 };
}
```